# Fails when an lock of an object exists in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I followed the example given [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms190345(v=sql.120).aspx) of `sys.dm_tran_locks`, but instead of the second session blocks until the rollback of the first session, I need it to fail automatically if the lock exists, perhaps wait for a little amount of time before it fails.

Is there any parameter that I could configure to get that behavior? Other solutions are welcome.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking here.

Comment: Normally, lock on a table blocks others from doing any change to this table. What i want is that when others trying to change data on that table, they recieve an error instead of staying waiting for unlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but instead of the second session blocks until the rollback of the first session, I need it to fail automatically if the lock exists, perhaps wait for a little amount of time before it fails.

you will need to add `SET` options to your query

```
SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 1800;  --milliseconds  
GO
```

when you run the above query in a second session,it will wait only for specified time and will return error